# Using imported JAR files within app

Tags: android

I believe this might be a silly question but I'm trying to use a jar file within my app and cannot find how to import it. I have successfully added the jar to my library:

[image]

I now just need to put it to use through the code. Is there an `import` statement that should have come with the file? As I cannot seem to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an import statement that should have come with the file?

In the Java code? Yes. For example: [where you copied the code from](https://github.com/nivwusquorum/Simple-Guitar-Tuner/blob/master/src/org/sidor/androidapps/simpletuner/SoundAnalyzer.java#L9)

> I'm trying to use a jar file within my app

Open `build.gradle`, look for `compile fileTree` line within `dependencies` block

You don't need to do anything if that line is there as it says "grab all JAR files in the `libs/` directory".

---

**Ideally**, though, you don't want a JAR file.

```
dependencies {
    ...

    // Add this line
    compile group: 'edu.emory.mathcs', name: 'JTransforms', version: '2.4'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's saying that it's an unused import statement. I have added the compile group to the gradle build and synced the project files. Any ideas? I got the jar files from here: https://github.com/nivwusquorum/Simple-Guitar-Tuner/blob/master/proguard.cfg

Comment: So? It's unused... That's just a warning, and won't crash the app.

Comment: And if you have the compile line, you can delete the jar file

Comment: so how can I add it to my app activity to actually put it to use?

Comment: I don't know what code that library contains, but you 1) `import` some Java classes, and 2) Use them. Sorry, I don't know what more you're asking.

Comment: For example. https://github.com/nivwusquorum/Simple-Guitar-Tuner/blob/master/src/org/sidor/androidapps/simpletuner/SoundAnalyzer.java#L9

Comment: this was the code I was looking for. Could I just copy all the code through and it will work as intended?

Comment: I would strongly suggest not copying code off the internet that you don't have some idea what it does